# How to check user is online in android studio

Tags: android, background, lifecycle

I have used the following code

```
public class AppControllerClass extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference stateRef;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    try {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    stateRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("user_state");

}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
public void onMoveToForeground() {

    stateRef.child("state").setValue("online");

    Log.i("AppActivity","foreground");
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
public void onMoveToBackground() {

    stateRef.child("state").setValue("offline");

    Log.i("AppActivity","background");
}
}
```

I have updated my code,

```
    onMoveToBackground()
```

is called when I get to the background, I can see the log AppActivity background
but once I return to the app the state update as offline and then

```
    onMoveToForeground()
```

is called and the state is quickly updated as online.

I don't know what gets wrong
why isn't the state is updated in the background
please someone, try and give me the working solution.

Comment: Please change you question to be more specific.. what does "How to check user is online" mean?

Comment: My question is when I update my database in onMoveToForeground() method it works like charm and as soon I return to foreground it updates it. While, onMoveToBackground() method don't update the database when I move to background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code to check app status using LifecycleObserver

**gradle**

```
  implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
```

**AppControllerClass**

```
 public class AppController extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public static DatabaseReference USERS_DATABASE,INBOX_DATABASE,MESSAGE_DATABASE;
    private static String TAG=AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
        try {
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            USERS_DATABASE = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(USER_TABLE);
            USERS_DATABASE.keepSynced(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
        }
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onMoveToForeground() {
        // app moved to foreground
        Log.e(TAG,"App is in foreground State");
        updateParticularField("onlineStatus","online");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onMoveToBackground() {
        // app moved to background
        Log.e(TAG,"App is in Background State");
        updateParticularField("onlineStatus","offline");
    }
    public void updateParticularField(String fieldName,String fieldValue){
        try {
            String currentFireBaseId=mAuth.getUid();
            if (!currentFireBaseId.equals("null")) {
                USERS_DATABASE.child(currentFireBaseId).child(fieldName).setValue(fieldValue);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Add  In Manifest**

```
android:name=".AppController"
```

And make sure your minSdkVersion=24

This code changed my online status on app foreground and background

Screenshots for firebase as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir but where to call  but where to call onMovedToBackground() and onMovedToForeground() methods. In the main activity??

Comment: No Need to call onMovedToBackground() and onMovedToForeground() methods in any activity, It is overriden in AppController and AppController controlls the whole app, it checked that app is in foregroud or background state, it handles the status of whole app not single activity. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply sir, I understood. but I have encountered a problem I update my database detail in onMovetoBackground() method and in onMovetoForeground() method . But when I move in background I can see log app_state background but the database is not updated. It update once I get back to foreground.while the onMovetoForeground() works like charm

Comment: sir please reply

Comment: In onCreate() of AppController class, add `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

Check edited answer, It may helps you.

Comment: I have done my best still can't get the solution, I have updated my question. on moving to background the log is shown but the database only update when I return back to the app and then onMoveToForeground() is called and again database is updated but why is the database not updating when I go to back ground. Sir,Please try it by yourself and if possible give me the solution.